# rollback mysql transcations from multiplate methods GWT

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

I'm trying to figure out how to rollback commits from multiple methods. I want to do something like the following (editing for brevity)

```
public void testMultipleMethodRollback() throws DatabaseException {
    Connection conn = connect();
    fakeMethodRollback1();
    fakeMethodRollback2();
    try {
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and currently all my methods are formatted like this

```
public void fakeMethodRollback1() throws DatabaseException {
    Connection con = connect();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    // insert some queries
    try {
        String query = "some query";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.executeUpdate(query);
        query = "some query";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.executeUpdate(query);
        con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new DatabaseException(e);
    } finally {
        close(rs, ps, conn);
    }
}
```

because I want to be able to use the other methods independently, how can I do a rollback where if one method fails, the others will roll back? I fear I have my whole class setup wrong or at least wrong enough that this can't be accomplished without major work. I can't change the methods to return a connection, because half of my methods are get methods, which are already returning other data. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking if `fakeMethodRollback2` failed then could you roll back `fakeMethodRollback1`?

Comment: yes I'm using GWT, and that is correct j.con, I should have made that a little clearer.

Comment: No, john, Alexey was asking what here is GWT-specific. You are asking a question about database transactions - which has nothing to do with GWT. By including the GWT tag, and not the relevant database/transaction related tags you are in effect asking the wrong bunch this question.